# org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi I am facing a very strange problem. I am using Spring MVC 3.0+Spring Security 3.2+hibernate 4.3. before login I am able to hit database and getting entity befor login. But after login by spring security, I am getting exception `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread`. This exception thrown on `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`

I have used transection management by AOP. My question is:

**Why excpetion come after login? While it is working fine before login?**

My Code is as below:

```
@Repository("categoryDAO")
public class CategoryDAOHibernateImpl implements CategoryDAO {

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public List<Category> findAll() {
    List<Category> list;
    try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Category.class);
        list = criteria.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BookStoreDAORuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return list;
}
}
```

FullStacktrace:

```
  StandardWrapperValve[appServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1012)
at com.abhendra.bookstore.common.entities.dao.hibernate.UserDAOHibernateImpl.findByEmail(UserDAOHibernateImpl.java:68)
at com.abhendra.bookstore.management.user.impl.UserManagementServiceImpl.findByEmail(UserManagementServiceImpl.java:20)
at com.abhendra.bookstore.LibreryController.showCategory(LibreryController.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]]
```

daoContext.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bookstore</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>bookstore</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>bookstore</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>Author.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>Book.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>Category.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>Comment.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>Download.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>Rating.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>Role.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>User.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            jdbc.use_getGeneratedKeys=true
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
            hibernate.generate_statistics=false

            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
            hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
        </value>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="defaultTxAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>



<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="dbServiceOperations"
        expression="execution(* com.abhendra.bookstore.common.entities.dao.*DAO*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="dbServiceOperations" advice-ref="defaultTxAdvice" />
</aop:config>
```

SecurityConfig:

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/bookstore/authentication/login"
        login-processing-url="/bookstore/authentication/loginProcess"
        default-target-url="/bookstore/home/index"
        authentication-failure-url="/bookstore/authentication/login?login_error=1" />
    <!-- authentication-failure-handler-ref="postFailedAuthHandler" -->
    <security:logout logout-url="/bookstore/authentication/logout"
        logout-success-url="/bookstore/authentication/login" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/bookstore/admin/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/bookstore/home/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>

<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.abhendra.core.spring.security.BookstoreAuthenticationProvider" />

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="false">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"></security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

rootContext.xml

```
<import resource="classpath:daoContext.xml" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.abhendra.bookstore, com.abhendra.core" />
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml, /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>   

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/bookstore/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>    
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Map all /resources requests to the Resource Servlet for handling -->
<!-- <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resources Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> -->

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bookstore/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks In Advance.:-)

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace, if too big can you use pastebin.com?

Comment: @jhadesdev Added StackTrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem without adding extra annotation(like @Transactional). I added this in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/bookstore/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

But I don't know why it solved and how. Can any one drop some light on it?

Comment: You have something that is lazy loaded. The object that lazy loaded is fetched(not exactly) in the DAO that is in a hibernate session. Then it's passed to some other method(or view in your case) that is not in hib session. When you try to access some property of the lazy loaded object, hibernate tries to fire select statement to the DB, but it's not inside a session... You can read about hibernate lazy loading, there are a lot of SO questions and articles about that

Answer (score 2):

The code is trying to get the current session, but there is no configuration for @Transactional that would allow for the container to add a session to the thread before calling an annotated method.

In the stacktrace we can see that LibreryController calls UserManagementServiceImpl, that calls UserDAOHibernateImpl, and there are no transactional proxies in the middle.

You should add support for @Transactional, annotate UserManagementServiceImpl with it and that should solve the problem. See this [blog post](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/spring-declarative-transactions-example.html) for how to do this.

Comment: Not working this trick. This code is working perfectly before login. But after login, it could not found session. I think it is related to spring security and due to Spring Security Session, hibernate is not getting session.

Answer (score 0):

try this will may help:

```
    try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Category.class);
        list = criteria.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BookStoreDAORuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @Transactional to your class. Modify your sessioFactory like this and add a setter:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

This is how it works for me. If that doesn't help, try opening the session yourself:

```
private Session session = null;
private Transaction tx = null;

public List<Category> findAll() {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to open and close session each time. I can not use `sessionFactory.openSession();`. I need to find solution for `getCurrentSession`. Please see my own solution.